# How to get the table name from the db variable name ? ( SQL )

Tags: sql, t-sql

How to get the table name from the db variable name ? ( SQL )

I have a variable to fetch the database name based on the DB Environment. Passing the DBName , i need to fetch the table names.

How to fetch Table Names from the DB Name assigned to a variable.

```
Declare @DBName nvarchar(1000)

set @DBName = ( select
CASE WHEN @@SERVERNAME='MyProdServer' THEN 'MyDB_Production'     
           WHEN @@SERVERNAME='MyTestServer' THEN 'MyDB_Test'
        ELSE '(Unknown)' End  as DBName )


select * from @DBName.dbo.MyTestTable
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use [Information Schema Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get table names from a specific database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a little bit of dynamic SQL

```
Declare @script varchar(max)

Set @script = 'select name from ' +  @dbname + '.sys.tables'

exec(@script)
```

or you can use

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG
     , TABLE_SCHEMA
     , TABLE_NAME
     , TABLE_TYPE
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_catalog=@dbname
```

what you can't do is switch to the table unless you continue to use dynamic sql:

```
Set @script - 'select * from # + @dbname + '.dbo.mytesttable'
Exec (@script)
```

I have used another method to get around this which is to store the script I want to run in a table using a placeholder.

```
CREATE myscripts as table (script varchar(max), upk int)

INSERT INTO myscripts
Select 'Select * from #10#.dbo.mytable', 1


Set @script=(Select script from mytable where upk=1)
Set @script=REPLACE(@script,'#10#', @dbname)

Exec(@script)
```

Comment: this is not going to help me. I have the same syntax. Problem is , i need to fetch a specific table from the variable. In other words, dynamically, we need to switch to the db .. use dbname

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: @goofyui, then your problem statement isn't clear. This answers how to "fetch Table Names from the DB Name assigned to a variable."

Comment: Thanks HABO - that's a handy tip.

Comment: this query ..is helpful .. FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_catalog=@dbname , I ended up using this query to fetch the table which i need .. Thanks